# How to calculate all possibilities of very large string matrixes timely?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix

OK so let's say I have a situation where I have a bunch of objects in different classifications and I need to know the total possible combinations of these objects so I end up with an input that looks like this

```
{'raw':[{'AH':['P','C','R','Q','L']},
{'BG':['M','A','S','B','F']},
{'KH':['E','V','G','N','Y']},
{'KH':['E','V','G','N','Y']},
{'NM':['1','2','3','4','5']}]}
```

Where the keys AH, BG, KH, NM constitute groups, the values are list that hold individual objects and a finished group would constitute one member of each list, in this example KH is listed twice so each finished group would have 2 members of KH in it.  I build something that handles this, it looks like this.

```
class Builder():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.raw = data['raw']
        node = []
        for item in self.raw:
            for k in item.keys():
                node.append({k:0})
        logger.debug('node: %s' % node)

        #Parse out groups#
        self.groups = []
        increment = -2
        while True:
            try:
                assert self.raw[increment].values()[0][node[increment][node[increment].keys()[0]]]
                increment = -2
                for x in self.raw[-1].values()[0]:
                    group = []
                    for k in range(0,len(node[:-1])):
                        position = node[k].keys()[0]
                        player = self.raw[k].values()[0][node[k][node[k].keys()[0]]]
                        group.append({position:player})
                    group.append({self.raw[-1].keys()[0]:x})
                    if self.repeatRemovals(group):
                        self.groups.append(group)
                node[increment][node[increment].keys()[0]]+=1
            except IndexError:
                node[increment][node[increment].keys()[0]] = 0
                increment-=1
                try:
                    node[increment][node[increment].keys()[0]]+=1
                except IndexError:
                    break
        for group in self.groups:
            logger.debug(group)

    def repeatRemovals(self, group):
        for x in range(0, len(group)):
            for y in range(0, len(group)):
                if group[x].values()[0] == group[y].values()[0] and x != y:
                    return False

        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    groups = Builder({'raw':[{'AH':['P','C','R','Q','L']},
                                           {'BG':['M','A','S','B','F']},
                                           {'KH':['E','V','G','N','Y']},
                                           {'KH':['E','V','G','N','Y']},
                                           {'NM':['1','2','3','4','5']}]})
    logger.debug("Total groups: %d" % len(groups.groups))
```

The output of running this should clearly state my intended goal, if I have failed to do so in text. My concern is the time it takes to handle large classification of objects, when a classification has some 40 something objects in it, it is in the matrix three times and there are 7 other classifications with comparable object sizes. I think the numpy library could help me, but I am new to scientific programming and am not sure how to go about it, or if it would be worth it, could anyone provide some insight? Thank you.

Comment: You could calculate it only with math! Remove duplicates and use permutations and factorials...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove duplicated values
2. Calculate all possibilities using permutation and factorial

Like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oc50d2GqXx0

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Try to explain the solution within the answer itself.

Comment: This is not even close to what I am looking for.